# How to implement custom HAProxy 404 responses?

Tags: loadbalancing

My goal is to build custom 404 http error code that will depend on a user's language. I thought that I can use header accept language.

I thought about something like this:

**#creating 2 acls that accepts only one accept language.**

```
acl en req.fhdr(accept-language),language(en;pl) -m str en
acl pl req.fhdr(accept-language),language(en;pl) -m str pl
```

**#and here i would like to use backends depends on acl's**

```
use_backend polish404 if pl
use_backend english404 if en

backend polish404
  mode http
  errorfile 503 /path/to/file

backend english404
  mode http
  errorfile 503 /path/to/file
```

Any ideas how to implement this?

@first_edit 7.07.2021

I've created this using [Samit's](https://devops.stackexchange.com/users/12138/samit) advice:

```
http-errors pl_ver
  errorfile 404 /path/to/file
http-errors en_ver
  errorfile 404 /path/to/file

acl en req.fhdr(accept-language),language(en;pl) -m str en
acl pl req.fhdr(accept-language),language(en;pl) -m str pl

http-response status 404 errorfiles pl_ver if { status 404 } { pl }
http-response status 404 errorfiles en_ver if { status 404 } { en }
```

Anyone have an idea how to implement this in other way?

@second_edit 24.07.2021

I've got a better implementation of that problem
for future seekers here you go:

```
# Defining HTTP errors
http-errors pl_ver
  errorfile 404 /path/to/file
http-errors en_ver
  errorfile 404 /path/to/file

# Setting variable (under frontend section)
  http-request set-var(txn.lang) req.hdr(Accept-Language)

# Feeding with response
  http-response return status 404 errorfiles pl_ver if { status 404 } { var(txn.lang) pl }
  http-response return status 404 errorfiles en_ver if { status 404 } { var(txn.lang) en }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of http-errors for creating different error code and file mappings.

After that, you can easily make use of `http-response` in haproxy config to return based on the error code. An example is below:

```
http-errors site1
    errorfile 404 /etc/haproxy/errors/site1-404.http

http-errors site2
    errorfile 404 /etc/haproxy/errors/site2-404.http

frontend allsites
    bind :80
    default_backend site1-servers
    use_backend site2-servers if { req.hdr(host) site2.com }

    # Store host header in variable
    http-request set-var(txn.host) req.hdr(host)

    # Use site1 error page if site1.com
    http-response return status 404 errorfiles site1 if { status 404 } { var(txn.host) site1.com }

    # Use site2 error page if site2.com
    http-response return status 404 errorfiles site2 if { status 404 } { var(txn.host) site2.com }
```

You can also dynamically generate different 404 error pages from a single template by passing the request parameters from haproxy to the error template.
I would recommend to go through this [haproxy blog](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/serve-dynamic-custom-error-pages-with-haproxy/) to understand in detail and try it out.